# Cannot stop perl

Tags: perl

I have a bot. My bot load on IRC. 
I Put global credit in my bot such as 100 Credit. Every people use my bot, credit will be decrease

Example :

```
Falcon check credit 99
Handy check credit 98
A check credit 97
```

In this case i wanna if credit has arrive to zero bot should stop checking. But if has arrive to 0 bot stop next, bot will work again if credit arrive -1

My Credit count down like this

```
    open(FILE, "+<freecredit.txt") or die "$! error";
    undef $/; 
    $number = <FILE>;
    $number = int($number);
    $credits = $number-1;
    seek(FILE, 0, 0); 
    truncate(FILE, tell FILE);
    print FILE $credits;
    close(FILE);

    if($credits == 0) {
    &respond_to_privmsg(\%msg,"Error : you must have credits to check");
    goto toEnd;
    }
    }

toEnd;
```

But if credit has through zero and arrive to -1 bot continue checking.
I wanna if credit has 0 bot will stop checker until i add credit to my bot.

Thanks for Helping :)

Comment: `if (!$number) { .. don't decrement .. }`

Comment: BTW I think the label `toEnd;` is wrong, it should be `toEnd:`.

Answer (score 7):

Your code is laid out very poorly, and appears to be the end of a loop, so it's hard to tell how it should look. You also seem to have written it without `use strict` and `use warnings` at the start: either that or you have declared everything at the top of the file, which is also a bad idea.

This may help you.

```
  open my $fh, '+<', 'freecredit.txt' or die "$! error";
  my $credits = <$fh>;

  if ($credits == 0) {
    respond_to_privmsg(\%msg, "Error : you must have credits to check");
    last;
  }

  $credits -= 1;

  truncate $fh, 0;
  seek $fh, 0, 0;
  print $fh $credits;
  close $fh;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I have use your script but see'ms like that :

```
    open my $fh, '+<', 'freecredit.txt' or die "$! error";
  my $credits = <$fh>;

  if ($credits == 0) {
print $credits;
    last;
  }

  $credits -= 1;

  truncate $fh, 0;
  seek $fh, 0, 0;
  print $fh $credits;
  close $fh;
```

error in CMD like this :

```
E:\>perl a.pl
Can't "last" outside a loop block at a.pl line 6, <$fh> line 1.
0
```

How fix it?